# Having trouble inserting cURL data into mysql with Simple Dom Parser

Tags: php, html, mysql, json, simple-html-dom

Hi I am trying to work out how to save my data to mysql once I have it scraped.
It won't insert anything into the database.I assume it's because the data I am passing is not in the right format? Do I need to post this via json?

```
    <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<?php

    //echo phpinfo();

    //include the php class to get the div content
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');//http:
    include_once('dbconn.php');

    //the name of the curl function
    function curl_get_contents($url){

    //Initiate the curl
    $ch=curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    //removes the header of the webpage
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    //do not display the whole page
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    //execute the curl
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    //close the curl so that resources are not wasted
    //curl_close($ch);
    return $output;

    ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
        }   




    $output = curl_get_contents('http://www.lockweb.com.au/en/site/lockweb/Products/?  groupId=469&productId=135');

    // Get the complete html from  the address

    $html = str_get_html($output);

    //get the title
        $title = $html->find('div.content-wide[id=content]', 0);
    $description = $html->find('div[class="tab-content content-wide selected"]',0);
    $spec = $html->find('div[class="tab-content content-wide"]',0);
    $moreinfo = $html->find('div[id=downloadsitem]',0);
    $image = $html->find('div.product-presentation',0);



    $echoHTML = "<table border=1 align=center>";
        $echoHTML .="<tr>";
        /* adding rows header to table */
                $echoHTML .="<th>Title</th>";
                $echoHTML .="<th>Description</th>";
                $echoHTML .="<th>Specifications</th>";
                $echoHTML .="<th>MoreInfo</th>";
                $echoHTML .="<th>Image/s</th>";
        $echoHTML .="</tr>";
        $echoHTML .="<tr>";
                $echoHTML .="<td>".$title->plaintext."</td>";
                $echoHTML .="<td>".$description->plaintext."</td>";
                $echoHTML .="<td>".$spec."</td>";
                $echoHTML .="<td>".$moreinfo."</td>";
                $echoHTML .="<td>".$image."</td>";

        /* end of table */
        $echoHTML .= "</table>";

        echo $echoHTML;
         //trying to insert the data into the database
           $q=  ("INSERT INTO  `lockwood`.`products` (
            `Title` ,
            `Descr` ,
            `Spec` ,
            `more info` ,
            `image` ,
            `id`
            )
            VALUES (
            '$title',  'teat',  'test',  'test',  'test', NULL"
            );

?>
```

Comment: the cURL func works, but i dont have simple dom to test the rest. are you sure you have retrieved data from the scrap process (dump it to screen with `var_dump`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are scrapping data and generating your table correctly...

The problem as you said, happens when you try to insert the html code into the database...

This code has to be escaped using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
$q=  sprintf(("INSERT INTO  `lockwood`.`products` (
        `Title` ,
        `Descr` ,
        `Spec` ,
        `more info` ,
        `image` ,
        `id`
        )
        VALUES (
        '%s',  'teat',  'test',  'test',  'test', NULL"
        ), mysql_real_escape_string($title));
```

OR

```
$q=  ("INSERT INTO  `lockwood`.`products` (
        `Title` ,
        `Descr` ,
        `Spec` ,
        `more info` ,
        `image` ,
        `id`
        )
        VALUES (
        ' {mysql_real_escape_string($title)} ',  'teat',  'test',  'test',  'test', NULL"
        );
```

Unfortunately, this function is deprecated and will be removed in the future... So depending on your need, use either [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or [PDO::quote()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

Comment: Thank you.Worked like a charm.Here is my solution for anyone who is wondering.


$q= mysql_query("INSERT INTO  `lockwood`.`products` (
   `Title` ,
   `Descr` ,
   `Spec` ,
   `more info` ,
   `image` 
   
   )
   VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($titlex)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($descriptionx)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($specx)."','test','test')");
     if (!$q)
       {
       die(mysql_error());
      }
     
     mysql_close($con);
     
     
     echo strip_tags($title);